# Any disadvantage of using GetStringAsync vs GetString for HttpClient?

Tags: c#

This question is related to entire "async-await" implementation.
I will keep it simple.
Example:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();  
string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
```

Is there any reason to use client.GetString()?

Why not just name GetStringAsync as GetString, and get rid of non-async GetString? And get rid of async-await keywords at all?

I read many posts, but didn't find a clear **simple** explanation.

Why create so many duplicate methods, what's the point? It just doesnt feel right. Give me a reason why use non-async method? Don't you want long running methods to use available threads and CPU cores to run things in parallel?
(obviously it has nothing to do with the web-based ajax async operations)

Comment: Have you considered backwards compatibility? If you upgrade the Framework version and suddenly none of your method calls work, that adds hours of work. Plus you may not always be in an async context.

Comment: What about it? previously in your code you had GetString(). Now, GetString() is implemented as asynchronous. Nothing changed. You code continues to work, only better.

Answer (score 6):

> Why not just name `GetStringAsync` as `GetString`, and get rid of non-async `GetString`?

There are two reasons for this:

- **Doing so would break backward compatibility** - programs that rely on `GetString` returning a `string` rather than a `Task<string>` would stop compiling, and
- **Requiring `await` would make it hard to use the API from non-`async` methods** - programmers would need to write additional code to wait for the task to complete.

Each of these considerations is disqualifying by itself.

Note that once your API is in use, you must be extremely cautious about "breaking changes", i.e. changes that break code relying on your API. Changing method's return type, along with a fundamental part of its functionality (synchronous vs. asynchronous) is definitely a breaking change.

Comment: 1. Forget about Task<string>, let the method return string, just implement it internally as asynchronous. Like in my example it doesn't return Task, it returns a string. 2. Forget about async and await keywords, get rid of them completely. What does it change? The code will be clean.

Comment: @monstro (1) A method that does not return a value as a `Task` cannot be asynchronous in C#. (2) If you drop async and await keywords, you would lose a great deal of flexibility. Specifically you wouldn't be able to invoke the task, and do something else before awaiting it.

Comment: 3) HttpClient is a .NET API, not a C# API.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, in my example: string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com"); this method does not return a Task, it returns a string. How it is implemented internally, I don't care.

Comment: @monstro Whether a method is synchronous or asynchronous is not an implementation detail that could be hidden from the users of the method. You cannot write an asynchronous method that returns a `string`, because such method would become synchronous - simply by virtue of returning a `string`.

Comment: That is exactly what I cant understand. "You cannot write an asynchronous method that returns a string" - Doesn't GetStringAsync return a string? Somehow they wrote it...

Comment: @monstro, try removing the await keyword and you'll see that GetStringAsync() is in-fact returning a Task<string>.
Also, I rarely use GetStringAsync() as it doesn't let you set the TaskCreationOptions. If you're not careful about the TaskCreationOptions, you can end up in scenarios where .NET will wait for a previous task to complete before spawning a new one. In some scenarios, that can lead to deadlocks.

Comment: @monstro [`GetStringAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746(v=vs.118).aspx) does not return a `string`, it returns `Task<string>`. When you add `await` before a call returning `Task<string>` C# adds extra code to stop, wait for the return, and harvest the `string`, making it look as if `GetStringAsync` returns `string` when it actually doesn't.